# Delete all tweets from personal twitter account

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-chrome-devtools

My Twitter account has been hacked and a scam posted about 500 scam-tweets from it.

**The task:** delete all tweets with JS in DevTools.

**My solution:**

```
const tweets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="tweet"]')
for (let i = 0; i<= tweets.length; i++) {
   //1. Click on a tweet to show the tweet-menu:
   setTimeout(() => {tweets[i].querySelector('[aria-label="More"]').click()}, 1000)

   //2. Click on delete option:
   setTimeout(() => {document.querySelector('[role="menuitem"]').click()}, 1000)

   //3. Approve deleting in popup:
   setTimeout(() => {document.querySelector('[data-testid="confirmationSheetConfirm"]').click()}, 1000)
}
```

**Problems:**

1. We need to scroll for more tweets and only then run it again.
2. Each step (1,2,3) is not waiting for the previous to end running.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the Twitter API, you can find the documentation here: [Twitter Developer API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api)

It allows you to log into your account with your API Key and post, delete and do basically everything with your account using code.

Alternatively, there is already a web application for bulk deleting tweets: [TweetDelete](https://tweetdelete.net/)

Comment: That you for these useful links. One day they will help me.

But the task was to delete all tweets through the DevTools with JS when you have been already signed in in your acc.

Comment: Oh, i didn't recognice that this was just for fun a challenge ^^ I thought you just wanted to delete the tweets and doing that with the DevTools is probably one of the worst methods to do so